# Helping to solve a regex pattern with a lack value in one group

Tags: regex

I have this original data:

```
one:1,two:2;one:11;one:111,two:222;one:1111,two:2222;one:11111,two:22222;
```

Expand data:

```
one:1      two:2
one:11
one:111    two:222
one:1111   two:2222
one:11111  two:22222
```

*(You can see there is not number two in the second group.)*

Now, I need to get all numbers.  I write this pattern:

```
one:(.*?),two:(.*?);
```

But it returns incorrect values in match number 2, see:

```
Match 2
Full match  `one:11;one:111,two:222;`
Group 1.    `11;one:111`
Group 2.    `222`
```

And my expected values:

```
Match 2
Full match  `one:11;`
Group 1.    `11`
Group 2.    ``
```

See Online:
https://regex101.com/r/Qm9tKG/1

Do you can advise me for resolve the pattern?

Comment: What is your regex flavor?

Comment: @anubhava , PHP , But I do not think it will affect the whole pattern.

Comment: Try [`one:([^,;]*)(?:,two:([^,;]*);)?`](https://regex101.com/r/O5QNVR/1).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew: That was my original solution but OP didn't like it expecting an empty group 2 match

Comment: Then the question is unclear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use this regex with an *optional match* and **branch reset group**:

```
one:(\d+)(?|,two:(\d+)|());
```

**RegEx Details:**

- `one:`: Match literal text `'one:`
- `(\d+)`: **1st capture group**. match 1 or more digits
- `(?|`: Start branch reset group

  - `,two:`: Match literal text `,two:`
  - `(\d+)`: **2nd capture group**. match 1 or more digits
  - `|`: OR
  - `()`: An empty group that will be numbered as **2nd capture group**
- `)`: End branch reset group
- `;`: Match literal `;`

[Updated RegEx Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Qm9tKG/4)

Comment: Thanks, But this is different from my expected result. I just need the numbers and I need the simplest possible pattern.

Comment: The `one:` and `two:` is in plain data and not important for me, `Full match` not important, I just need numbers as groups. (see results of my sample)

Comment: 5  to make it 500K. Congrat.

Comment: @revo: Thanks so much, really appreciate it.

Answer (score 1):

Here is one option you may try:

```
(one:\d+[,;]((?!one:\d+[,;]).)*)
```

### Demo

The basic idea is to match anything appearing after the first `one` entry, provided that it is not again another `one` entry.  The above pattern generated the following matches:

```
Match 1
Full match  0-12    `one:1,two:2;`
Match 2
Full match  12-19   `one:11;`
Match 3
Full match  19-35   `one:111,two:222;`
Match 4
Full match  35-53   `one:1111,two:2222;`
Match 5
Full match  53-73   `one:11111,two:22222;`
```

To generate your exact expected output, I would do an additional step to format and remove the punctuation, if you really don't want it there.

Comment: Thanks, But this is different from my expected result. I just need the numbers and I need the simplest possible pattern.

Comment: @NabiK.A.Z. You never posted your code, but if you're using PHP, it should be easy for you to do a little processing on each possible match to remove punctuation and non numbers, leaving you with what you want.  You shouldn't expect a single regex to be a universal panacea for your problems.